# How to print the dataframe table to the screen using PHP by invoking python code?

Tags: php, python, pandas

This is my Php code here, I don't know Php sorry about that.
well i tried a bit.

```
<?php
    $command=escapeshellcmd("C:/user/www/php/demo.py");
    $output=shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
?>
<html>
<body>

<script> 
console.log(<?php echo $output ?>);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What i am trying here like i have a python code that give output as dataframe with multiple rows and columns, So now i need to display the table to simple web browser by using php.

Her is my sample python code:

```
import pandas as pd
dict={1:2,3:4,5:6,7:8}
df=pd.DataFrame(list(dict.items()),columns={'a','b'})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
3  7  8
```

Summary:
I need to show this output to the screen using php. Kindly help me with posting a code if possible.

Comment: What do you see with your current php script?

Comment: Nothing.....its blank

Comment: Ok, so for me it's working locally, but i am on a linux system. So your command might be malformed, as it is not executing the python file correctly. Try to fix it, and you will make it work, as your PHP Script is correct.

Comment: @Tyralcori Sorry i dont understand what to change?In python file only?

Comment: The command itself is probably not correct -> "C:/user/www/php/demo.py", if you type that in your CLI, do you trigger the python script? Try to execute this instead:
$output=shell_exec("C:/user/www/php/demo.py");

Comment: I tried but its not working.

Comment: But if you execute the same exact command in your CLI, the python script is being executed successfully?

Comment: maybe you should use `"C:\full\path\to\python.exe C:\full\path\to\script.py"`